# how to display context for company events in BI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, business-intelligence

I am encountering a problem in BI (data visualization over historical data) that isn't unique to any BI tool (e.g., Power BI, Qlik Sense, Tableau).  I need a way to add context (e.g., descriptive text) to certain events in my company's historical data, such that we don't need to explain anomalies in data visuals to new users of a report.  For example, in a visual of sales over time, we want verbiage to appear in a tooltip for certain points in time.  This verbiage will be created by report users and saved (somehow).  So, this is like storytelling in BI, but with the difficulty that the verbiage / context needs to remain after dataset refreshes.  It would be ideal to have this be tool-agnostic, but it's fine if it needs to be tool-specific (e.g., using Power BI's comments feature).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You could load a table of commentary (maintained, say, via a SharePoint list) into your data model and then write a measure that returns the text if it matches the date / dimension combination.

Answer (score 1):

For summary reports (that display aggregated values) you may include these descriptive texts into the report as a special measure.

For example, let's assume that your report displays sales amount per year/month/category. In terms of SQL data for this report is loaded with a query like that:

```
select year(date_col) as dim_year, month(date_col) as dim_month, sum(amount) as sales_amount from transactions
group by 1, 2
```

To display some commentary text it should be joined to the aggregation result - for example:

```
select dim_year, dim_month, sales_amount, c.comment as sales_amount_comment from (
  select year(date_col) as dim_year, month(date_col) as dim_month, sum(amount) as sales_amount 
  from transactions
  group by 1, 2
) res
left join comments c on (c.year=res.dim_year and c.month=res.dim_month)
```

(assuming that `comments` table has columns `year`, `month`, `comment`)

Next steps depend on your BI tool, in most cases you can simply display 2 measures (sales_amount and sales_amount_comment) in the pivot table, if BI tools allows custom HTML formatting this could be a one table cell that shows amount value and displays the comment on mouse over (say, wrapped with `<div title='comment text'>`) or smth like that.

It is up to you how users will populate `comments` table; it can be loaded from Google Sheets, or simple custom CRUD app may be used to add/edit records.